# Is it right to have large partial dependence value?

Tags: python, boosting, partial-dependency-plots

I am trying to plot the Partial Dependence of built form against energy consumption (kwh/year) in python. As shown in the attached chart, so it returned a plot with huge partial dependence on the y-axis. The model was a gradient boosting model, and the input y is around the similar range of what is showing in the y-axis.

But as far as I searched, all the online examples have small values in the y-axis. Usually ranges from 0-1 and I would assume that kind of chart can be read as the change in probabilities of having an x and getting the y.

So does that mean it is wrong to have such a big value as partial dependence? Or it should be read differently than probabilities?

Many thanks

[image]

Comment: You have a regression problem thus the values on the vertical axis reflect energy consumption values. However, typically we do not bother about the values themselves but about the shape of the plot.

Comment: @utobi Many thanks! Such a relief to know this is fine...